# Regex - Match only unicode alphabet not numbers

Tags: php, regex, validation, unicode

I'm using PHP, and trying to write a regular expression that matches any alphabet in any language but not numbers.

I've tried `/\p{L}+/` But it matches unicode alphabets and numbers too. I'm checking against Arabic and English languages. English numbers doesn't pass which is normal, but Arabic numbers pass which is not normal.

Is there another regular expression that matches only alphabets in any language ?

Comment: did you try to add anchors? and did you use the u modifier?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Can you elaborate more what do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: something like this: `/\A\pL+\z/u`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks it worked. I added `u` flag and it solved it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: An about the anchors `\A` and `\z` are they needed?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No. the alphabet can be anywhere in the matched string. Not at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex engine need to know that the target string is an unicode string (to avoid interpretation errors). To do that you can use the u modifier, that has two functions:

- it expands classical shorthand character classes like `\w` `\d` to unicode characters (and not only ascii characters)
- it forces the string to be seen as an unicode string

So you can use: `/\pL+/u`

Note that in your particular case, the first behavior is not needed, but you can only switch on the second behavior with: `/(*UTF8)\pL+/` (`(*UTF8)` must be placed at the very begining of the pattern)